# Yii component property not calling get, when using getAttributes

Tags: php, model, yii

I have a Model with a [Component property](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.component#component-property). This value should be pre-calculated every time, when I initialize/get this Model (there is a function that generates it).

I placed this 'default value' into the getter of the property:

```
public function getCid(){
    if ($this->_cid == null ){
        $this->_cid = generateCid();
    }
    return $this->_cid;
}
```

When I call it, its get method is properly working:

```
$model->cid; //returns good value
```

But, when I try to get it with other parameters with `getAttributes()` function, it doesn't call it's get method.

```
$model->getAttributes(array('cid')); //just to try only this property.
```

I don't want to trick with arrays to get it's value independently with `$model->cid` and merge it into the `getAttributes` return array, because I will have lot more properties in my app and I am looking for a fast solution.

So where should I move this generator, or what should I change to get this generated id easily?

**Update:**

I created a base ActiveRecord class, that is extending the `CActiveRecord` and I added the following function:

```
public function getAttributes($names=true){
    $base = parent::getAttributes($names);
    foreach($base as $key => $value)
        if(!$this->hasAttribute($key))
            $base[$key] = $this[$key];

    return $base;
}
```

This calls every added attribute's get method, so it will update it's content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your actual model a `CActiveRecord` model?

Based on what is shown as part of [CModel::getAttributes()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel#getAttributes-detail), there would be different ways to handle this depending on your model type.

But your quickest way to handle it would probably be to override `getAttributes` in your model and have it do a custom call to your getter if the `'cid'` value is found in the array you pass in.

You'll probably want to look at [CActiveRecord::getAttributes()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#getAttributes-detail) for ideas, override it and then call your `parent::getAttributes()` from your custom override.

Comment: I tried something like this, but it can't run, because this method using the protected `_attributes` variable.

My solution is, to loop through every attributes and call what is not a real attribute.
I attached my solution in another answer, so everyone can see the syntax well :)
But thanks, it was based in your idea.